# ASMX web service works in IE11 but not in FF or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, asmx

Hey all I have an issue with getting my ASMX web service to work in Chrome and Firefox. Oddly enough it works just fine in IE 11.....

My AJAX:

```
var sqlQ = "SELECT * FROM vwPS_DAT WHERE OID = 'g643j'";

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    crossDomain : true,
    dataType : "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    },
    url : "http://zzzzzzz/sqlWS/Service1.asmx/theQ",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data : JSON.stringify({qString : [sqlQ]}),
    success : function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function (response) {
        alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText + " " + response.responseText);
    }
});
```

What I get from IE:

```
[{"BC_ACTION":"P","ACTION_DT":"\/Date(1400817600000)\/","BAS_GROUP_ID":"   ","DESCR":"Operations".....etc etc..
```

What I get in Chrome:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error).
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://zzzzzz/sqlWS/Service1.asmx/theQ.
>   Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

What am I missing to cause it to not work in Chrome/FF but work in IE11?

Comment: "Response for [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) has invalid HTTP status code 500". Most likely your ASMX isn't handling the preflight request that browsers supporting CORS send.

Comment: Also, are you really sending raw SQL commands from JavaScript to your server?

Comment: Why do you have beforeSend, cache, async, and crossDomain options set? they're all either redundant or don't do anything in this situation.